# Identification of a capacitor

Tags: capacitor

I have here some capacitors (electrolytic, I assume), and I can not identify their capacitance. There are two numbers printed on it:
+15
+35V
So, I assume that it has 15 µF and holds till 35 V, is this correct?
Edit: Photo:
[image]

(The blue one in the middle)

Comment: Can you attach a photo of it?

Comment: A picture is necessary, or at least a *detailed* description.

Comment: @hkBattousai: Photo is attached.

Comment: That don't look like a cap at all, more like a [varistor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varistor). It does not seem your board would need a varistor though, to be sure I'd say a photo of both front and back of the board is needed, plus some infos on what the board is doing. Just knowing where the components terminal are connected would be good.

Comment: @VladimirCravero: See here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/127895/how-to-start-reverse-engineering-a-circuit for more information about the board. And btw. it is placed between VCC and GND.

Comment: On old equipment, they are common source of failures. You should replace it.

Comment: @venny: With a new one?

Comment: that's a tantalium cap then

Comment: @arc_lupus Yes, or better with low-ESR aluminium electrolytic capacitor.

Comment: Ok, I am thinking of it if we want to reuse the board. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's highly likely that this is a [tantalum capacitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tantalum_capacitor).

[image]
([Source](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-read-a-tantalum-capacitor.php))

According to this information, it is 15\$\mu\$F in capacitance and has a rated voltage of 35V. The positive lead is the one below where the `+` signs are.

Answer (score 4):

This is a tantalum or possibly solid-electrolyte electrolytic capacitor. The + indicates which lead is positive.

The solid-electrolyte capacitors I have seen were all bright orange and manufactured by Philips (now NXP I suppose) so I would believe they are probably tantalum.

Which means beware if the +ve supply is a high current supply... tantalums can fail unexpectedly. But when they work, they usually have longer life and lower leakage than wet electrolytics.

Varistor is unlikely as I don't believe they are polarised...

Comment: Last time I had a tant fail on me there was a blue flash, an explosion and a piece of it buried in my finger. I don't like them.

Comment: I do like them : but not if there's any power behind the supply, for the reason you noted!